# Generalised gauss's law

Tags: gauss-law, vector-fields

Considering a particle can produce a field with potential,
$$\phi=1/r^n$$
where n is a positive integer,

If the particles density distribution in space is $\rho(r)$, then the potential,
$$\phi (r)=\iiint_V d^3r' \rho(r')/(r'-r)^n$$

I wonder if it possible to write a differential equation for the potential. For a specific case, n=1, then $\Delta \phi=\rho$, which is the gauss's law.